# I need a schematron rule that enforces the existance of an attribute only if another attribute exists first.

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xslt-2.0, schematron

I am trying to write a schematron rule as such: 
    The owner attribute exists only if the name attribute exists. For example:

```
<business name="n1" owner="o1" />
```

the owner attribute can only exist if the name attribute exists. Thanks!

Comment: If you can use XSD 1.1 you can add an `<xs:assert>`, you don't need a schematron. Do you really need an schematron? (Note you have tagged your question with xsd, thus I assume you already have a schema).

Comment: @potame: With due respect, Schematron has its advantages.  Perhaps a fairer objection to raise would simply be why a question on Schematron has an XSD tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can assert that either both `@owner` and `@name` exists, or `@owner` does not:

```
<rule context="business">
  <assert test="(@owner and @name) or not(@owner)">
    The owner attribute requires the name attribute.
  </assert>
</rule>
```